# Promises with ES6 destructuring?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I've tried mixing `Promises` with ES6 destructuring syntax (just for experimentation purposes) but the following code throws an error:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)
  })
}

const { then } = delay(2000)

console.log(typeof then) // ==> 'function'

// throws TypeError:
then(() => {
  console.log(`done!`)
})
```

On Node.js v7.10.1 it prints:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(promise_state_symbol)' of undefined

Chrome console also throws a `TypeError`, but with a different message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver undefined

These errors don't say much to me. What's better explanation for this?

Comment: When you pull `.then()` out of the Promise object, the subsequent function call won't have the correct `this` value.

Comment: What's the use case of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Assigning the `then` method to a variable, but `then` accesses `this`. You could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to achieve what you want.

Basically methods in javascript are just functions that are using `this`. If you are “stealing” the function and don't supply a this value, you are in dangerous territory.

Also the `then` you're extracting is most likely from `Promise.prototype`, not a function specific to the delay function.

You just found a fancy way to get the method from the object. It has not much to do with destucturing at all…

```
let p;
const {then} = p = delay(2000);
const then1 = p.then;

console.assert(then === Promise.prototype.then)
console.assert(then1 === then, 'thens aren\'t the same')
```

But you want a `then`, that somehow ensures, that you call it on the right promise.

So you could either go with

```
const p = delay(2000);
const then = p.then.bind(p);
…
```

Or construct another anonymous function

```
const p = delay(2000);
const then = fn => p.then(fn)
```

Note that this is not what you want, because it start the timeout when you are calling your `then`.

```
const then = fn => delay(2000).then(fn) // ⚠ setTimeout gets called when you are calling then.
```

I see no way how you would achieve what you want in one line, but maybe others have an idea.

Answer (score 3):

It means that [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is a method and you did not call it on any instance - you just called it as a function without any [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (or "receiver", as the second error message names it properly). You essentially did

```
const then = Promise.prototype.then
console.log(typeof then) // ==> 'function'
then(() => {}) // throws TypeError
```

You could use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
const promise = delay(2000);
then.call(promise, console.log);
```

or just properly invoke `promise.then(console.log)`.